# the front was broken

Tags: meaning

*The front was broken by a line of French windows.*

I would like to ask how to exactly understand the above sentence. Does it just mean that the windows in the front were broken or is it some sort of a metaphor?

Comment: The facade was visually interrupted by the windows.

Comment: I think @TRomano is right. Nevertheless, it would help if we knew what "the front" referred to. The word _front_ is a [very](http://www.onelook.com/?w=front&ls=a) flexible word.

Comment: Front here = Front Facade

Comment: If it's about a building, the word frontage would have been more appropriate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @TRomano commented, it means the architectural facade of the building was visually interrupted ("broken up") by a line of French windows, which typically open in the middle and are made up of numerous vertically oriented rectangular panes of clear glass, rather than one large pane. In some countries, "French windows" are also apparently synonymous with "French doors." In the U.S., French doors are currently all the rage with homebuilders and renovators and come in various sizes and designs. From Wikipedia:

> "A French window (when hinged, a French door) is a large door-sized lattice light, typically set in pairs or multiples thereof. Known as *porte-fenêtre* in France and *portafinestra* in Italy, they often overlook a terrace and are commonly used in modern houses."

French doors open in the middle, making a large opening that lets in lots of air and light while facilitating the delivery (or removal) of large pieces of furniture. The latter can pose a security concern, as many French doors, especially older ones, are easier for a burglar to open from the outside than a solid single door.

If you do a Google search on "architectural facade with french windows - images" you will see many excellent examples of French windows on the front of older buildings in Europe, "breaking up" the facade into horizontal lines of vertical windows. If you do another search of just "french windows - images" you will see many modern examples of French windows and French doors, many of which are double-paned for better insulation and set in sturdy metal frames for greater strength.